# Describing relative performance of models on the basis on log-loss / cross-entropy

Tags: model-comparison, cross-entropy, log-loss

Suppose I train classification algorithms on a given dataset with three model specifications: A, B, and C. On validation data, model A has an average log-loss of 1.0, model B has a log-loss of 0.75, and model C has a log-loss of 0.5. I would like a way to describe the relative performance of these three models which has some kind of quantitative interpretation.

For example, is the absolute difference in log-loss a meaningful quantity? Does it make sense to say that model B is 0.25 better than model A?

What about the percent difference? Is model B 25% better than model A?

Is C "as much better" than B as B is than A?

As an example, if I were comparing models on the basis of AIC, I know that the absolute difference in AIC is a quantity with a meaningful interpretation (i.e., it is related to the relative probabilities that the model specifications are correct), whereas the percent change in AIC is not a meaningful quantity.

Comment: One useful fact is that if you have $k$ classes, the *expected* cross-entropy score corresponding to random assignment of probabilities is $\log(k)$, so one option is to compare the three models in terms of their improvement relative to the random model.